# System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch: batch apex job enqueue failed

Tags: apex, batch, integration, asynchronous, asyncapexjob

I have a batch class which updates a set of records with data from an external system. About twice a month or so, this exception is thrown: errorCode":"APEX_ERROR","message":"System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch: batch apex job enqueue failed."

This batch class runs daily and usually works fine. I have been unable to replicate the issue in a Sandbox even when I'm using the exact same payload that originally caused the issue. I'm thinking this may be some limit being hit. Has anyone faced an issue like this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might potentially have a condition that enqueues two jobs from time to time.